# Is object copied to the calling function as returned value a lvalue or rvalue?

Tags: c++, return-value

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Myclass{
    public:
    int a=3;
    Myclass& operator=(const Myclass& obj){
    a=obj.a;
    return *this;
}
    Myclass operator+(Myclass& obj){
    Myclass temp;
    temp.a=a+obj.a;
    return temp;
}
};
int main()
{
    Myclass A;
    Myclass B;
    B=A+B;
    cout<<B.a;
    return 0;
}
```

I read a code from the book. It is originally written for strings but I rewrote it with integer to simplify my question.

My question is :
The overloaded operator + function return a Myclass object.I think that this object is a rvalue.
Then why can it be passed as an argument of operator= function? It needs a reference of Myclass object, which is a lvalue.

Why can this code run successfully?

Comment: Generally, if it has a name, then it's an lvalue. So the result of `A + B` is an rvalue, but `B` is an lvalue.

Comment: `const Myclass& obj` can bind to rvalue or lvalue.  `Myclass& obj`  (note the missing `const`) can only bind to lvaules.

Comment: Const lvalue references are allowed to bind to rvalues. Also note that objects don't have a value category (lvalue-ness/rvalue-ness), that's a property of expressions (pieces of source code referring to objects). The same object can have several expressions referring it to it, with different value categories; but this doesn't affect anything here.

Comment: Write a function `void foo(MyClass&)` and one `void bar(MyClass const&)` and you will see that `foo(B)` is fine and so is `bar(B)` but `foo(A+B)` will be rejected while `bar(A+B)` will be fine.

Comment: As mentioned by others, references to const values can bind to rvalues. In any case, a very good rule to remember is that if you can take the address of something (apply the "&" operator to it), then it's very likely an lvalue. An rvalue is usually a temporary object (you can't apply the "&" to temporaries). Function parameters are always lvalues since you can apply the "&" operator to them, even if they're of type "&&", i.e., rvalue references. The "*can you take the adddress rule*" isn't always perfect in reality, but in general it works for most intents and purposes.

Comment: [Why is it possible to pass an rvalue by const lvalue reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58062090/why-is-it-possible-to-pass-an-rvalue-by-const-lvalue-reference)